# Remove ?=collcc from url

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

Google Webmasters Tools has notified me about too many duplicated URLs. Some parameters have been added that I don't know about and I need to remove it, for example:

```
http://example.com/5454/my-utr.html
http://example.com/5454/my_url.html?collcc=3067605522&
```

And this is marked as a duplicate URL on Google. How can I block `?=collcc` or remove it with `.htaccess`. Or preferably remove just `?collcc=` and redirect to the normal URL with `.htaccess`?

I know I can block in `robots.txt` file but I need clean URL still indexed on Google so I need to remove just the query `collcc`.

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} collcc=
RewriteRule (.*) http://my-site.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} collcc=
> RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
> ```

This should already have "worked". It should have removed any query string, providing "collcc=" was found *anywhere* in the requested URL's query string.

This is assuming you aren't getting any "errors" and mod_rewrite is already enabled, with the appropriate directives. For example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

The other possibility is that your directives are located in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file which is resulting in a conflict with existing directives. This redirect will need to go near the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, before any existing rewrites.